# Cant install PyTorch using pip on Windows

Tags: installation, pytorch

Hi after pasting this command to console: `pip install torch==1.7.1+cpu torchvision==0.8.2+cpu torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` (as shown on PyTorch website) I get this error:

```
C:\Users\m.povilaika>pip install torch==1.7.1+cpu torchvision==0.8.2+cpu torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Collecting torch==1.7.1+cpu

  Using cached https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.7.1%2Bcpu-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (184.2 MB)

Collecting torchvision==0.8.2+cpu

  Using cached https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torchvision-0.8.2%2Bcpu-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (804 kB)

Collecting torchaudio===0.7.2

  Using cached https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torchaudio-0.7.2-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl (103 kB)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\m.povilaika\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from torch==1.7.1+cpu) (1.19.4)

Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in c:\users\m.povilaika\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from torch==1.7.1+cpu) (3.7.4.3)

Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=4.1.1 in c:\users\m.povilaika\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from torchvision==0.8.2+cpu) (8.1.0)

Installing collected packages: torch, torchvision, torchaudio

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\m.povilaika\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python39\\site-packages\\caffe2\\python\\serialized_test\\data\\operator_test\\collect_and_distribute_fpn_rpn_proposals_op_test.test_collect_and_dist.zip'
```

Please help, I don't usually use windows, not sure what to do about the path error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your life will be easier if you use conda to install your packages. Do you have anaconda installed? `conda install torch`

Comment: Thanks that worked, had to also download c++. However now for some reason when I try to run easyocr on jupyter kernel dies. Do u know the solution to that?

Comment: Look into creating an environment in conda with all the packages you want. Then do `conda activate env_that_i_just_made`, in the conda command prompt then load jupyter `jupyter notebook` in the same command prompt.